# How to convert mysql dump(script) from version 5.0 to 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have mysql dump script, from mysql 5.0 server. And don't have access to this server. I need convert the script for mysql 5.7 dump.
this mysql script have error set default timestamp by CURRENT_TIME and etc. errors.

Comment: can you elaborate your question with example?

Comment: There is no magic bullet here, I'm afraid. Error by error you need to rewrite your script manually.

Comment: @Shadow I'm too afriad